# Google compute instance froze

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, google-compute-engine

I am running several instances with Ubuntu 14.04 with a custom kernel. All was great (for about a week or two) but for some reason my instances started freezing when booting - I get an "ssh operation time out" message and I can see that the CPU is at 50%.

I already tried to detach the virtual disk and attach it onto a new machine - but this causes the same behaviour on the new generated machine.

Comment: Did you follow [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/building-images#providedkernel) for building your custom kernel?

Comment: actually I wasn't aware of these, thanks @MishaBrukman I will look into those and update if it worked!

Comment: Any updates on your custom VM image build?